# How override FOSUserBundle form in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I want override the form of RegistrationType of FOSUserBundle, but in the registration_content.html.twig template I got this error:

> Neither the property "firstname" nor one of the methods "firstname()", "getfirstname()"/"isfirstname()"/"hasfirstname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

This my RegistrationType Form:

```
    class RegistrationType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('firstname');
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

fos_user.yaml:

```
fos_user:
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
    form:
        name: app_user_registration
db_driver: orm
user_class: App\Entity\User
firewall_name: main
from_email:
    address: foo@example.com
    sender_name: bar@example.com
```

User Entity:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
     //

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $firstname;
}
```

registration_content.html.twig:

```
    {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register', 'id': 'form-sign-up'}}) }}
                <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                    {{ form_widget(form.firstname, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    <label>{{ 'firstname'|trans }}</label>
                    <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In my config service I've already put this:

```
app.form.registration:
        class: App\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

Comment: Not sure how much of the `User` class you cut for including it in the question but did you add getter and setter for additional properties? As `$firstname` is protected you need to have a `getFirstname` and a `setFirstname` methods.

Comment: @dlondero Yes, I've already added the setter methods

Comment: Cache cleared? You know...

Comment: Nothing, even with cache:clear

Answer (score 5):

### Working Example

**Symfony 4.2.3 | friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.2**

Overrides FOSUserBundle registration form with our own class and remove the 'username' field for the sake of an example.

From your symfony root directory:

1. `mkdir ./src/Form/Type`
2. `cp ./vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php`
3. Edit `./config/packages/fos_user.yaml`

```
# fos_user.yaml
fos_user:

    #... other configurations...

    registration:
        form:
            type: App\Form\Type\RegistrationType
```

4. Edit `./src/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php`

```
// Our specific example. edit this as you please...
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->remove('username');
    }
    public function getParent() {
        return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Since our example is only removing a single field, we remove the code we are not changing and add the following method to keep things simple:

```
public function getParent() {
    return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
}
```

- Most of this information was aquired from [@Gabriel Deschamps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504181/2974621) and [@Robert Saylor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51766715/2974621) answer.
- I did not look into the `getParent` method but it seems to inherit from the original `RegistrationFormType.php` and simply add our changes made in the `buildForm` method.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue when following the official tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

I can't explain why we got this issue but it seems related to aliases. Anyway, I can't get it working in Symfony4 and in Symfony 3.4 neither !

I used the following code to circumvent the problem :

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname');
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

}
```

And then add this line to your fos_user.yaml :

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            type: App\Form\Type\RegistrationType
```

I hope this will help, until someone find a way to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder named Form in your src directory
2. Create a file named RegistrationFormType.php and add the following content:

   namespace App\Form;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

   use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

   class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType

   {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {

```
        $builder

            ->add('first');

        $builder
            ->add('last');

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
    }
}
```

The above is assuming you have added two new fields to your User entity and that you have ran your Doctrine migrations to add the new fields.
Tip: set the fields as nullable so you do not the FOS command line tools.

3. Add the following to your fos_users.yaml file in config/packages

registration:

```
form:

    type: App\Form\RegistrationFormType
```

4. Add the following to services.yaml:

   app.form.registration:

   ```
   class: App\Form\RegistrationFormType
   ```

Refresh your form and your new fields will be in the form.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did the same thig as Robert Saylor but edited this:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}
```

That worked fine to me !